# ServiceStack.MsgPack+DateTimeOffset 'Stream Unexpectedly Ends'

Tags: c#, servicestack, msgpack

I've been trying to convert our service stack app host and client to use MsgPack serialization. I kept getting the exception

```
MsgPack.InvalidMessagePackStreamException Stream Unexpectedly Ends
```

After some investigation I've tracked it down to `DateTimeOffset` field in the response object.

**Client Code**

```
using System;

namespace Client
{
    using Server;

    using ServiceStack.MsgPack;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new MsgPackServiceClient("http://localhost:1337");

            var response = client.Get(new GetRequest());

            Console.WriteLine("Response: [{0}] {1}", response.Timestamp, response.Result);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Server Code**

```
using System;

namespace Server
{
    using System.Reflection;

    using ServiceStack;
    using ServiceStack.MsgPack;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var listeningOn = args.Length == 0 ? "http://localhost:1337/" : args[0];
            using (var appHost = new AppHost("Test", Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(GetService))))
            {
                appHost.Init()
                    .Start(listeningOn);

                Console.WriteLine("AppHost Created at {0}, listening on {1}", DateTime.Now, listeningOn);

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }

    public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
    {
        public AppHost(string serviceName, params Assembly[] assembliesWithServices)
            : base(serviceName, assembliesWithServices)
        {
        }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            Plugins.Add(new MsgPackFormat());
        }
    }

    [Route("/GetRequest", Verbs = "GET")]
    public class GetRequest : IReturn<GetResponse> { }

    public class GetResponse
    {
        public string Result { get; set; }

        public string Timestamp { get; set; }
        //public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }
    }

    public class GetService : Service
    {
        public GetResponse Get(GetRequest request)
        {
            return new GetResponse { Result = "Success", Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString() };
            //return new GetResponse { Result = "Success", Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow };
        }
    }
}
```

The example works without `DateTimeOffset` but fails with the exception when its included.

The `MessagePackSerializer` class appears to work as expected as demonstrated by the following test.

```
public static void SerializeTest()
{
    var response = new GetResponse { Result = "Success", Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow };
    var serializer = MessagePackSerializer.Get<GetResponse>();

    var asSingleObject = serializer.PackSingleObject(response);
    var fromSingleObject = serializer.UnpackSingleObject(asSingleObject);

    var packStream = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.Pack(packStream, response);

    packStream.Position = 0;
    var fromPackStream = serializer.Unpack(packStream);

    packStream.Position = 0; 
    serializer.PackTo(Packer.Create(packStream), response);

    packStream.Position = 0;
    var fromPacker = serializer.Unpack(packStream);
}
```

In each case the response is packed\unpacked correctly with DateTimeOffset property.

I've tried custom serializer for DateTimeOffset but that fails the same way.

MsgPack.Cli 0.5.7
ServiceStack 4.0.35

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the [.NET MessagePack Serializer](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-cli), you can [submit an issue](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-cli/issues)

Comment: For completeness, please edit your question to include your code (more specifically, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example).

Comment: @mythx issue added https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-cli/issues/59